# gRPC server pytest error: statusCode.UNKNOWN

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I implemented a small server and try with pytest to validate it:

```py
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_poc_server():
    # Start poc server
    server = PoCGrpcServer(50051)
    await server.start()
    # Create a client that connects to the server
    async with grpc.aio.insecure_channel('localhost:50051') as channel:
        stub = PoCStub(channel)
        response = await stub.Move(poc__pb2.MoveRequest(x=10.0, y=10.0))
    assert response.result() == poc__pb2.MoveResponse
```

And the test fails on the `stub.Move()` with the following error:

```bash
>           response = await stub.Move(poc__pb2.MoveRequest(x=10.0, y=10.0))

tests/test_grpc_server.py:51: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <_AioCall of RPC that terminated with:
        status = Exception calling application: 
        details = "StatusCode.UNKNOWN"
        debu...peer  {created_time:"2023-06-15T14:38:59.0601+02:00", grpc_status:2, grpc_message:"Exception calling application: "}"
>

    def __await__(self) -> ResponseType:
        """Wait till the ongoing RPC request finishes."""
        try:
            response = yield from self._call_response
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            # Even if we caught all other CancelledError, there is still
            # this corner case. If the application cancels immediately after
            # the Call object is created, we will observe this
            # `CancelledError`.
            if not self.cancelled():
                self.cancel()
            raise
    
        # NOTE(lidiz) If we raise RpcError in the task, and users doesn't
        # 'await' on it. AsyncIO will log 'Task exception was never retrieved'.
        # Instead, if we move the exception raising here, the spam stops.
        # Unfortunately, there can only be one 'yield from' in '__await__'. So,
        # we need to access the private instance variable.
        if response is cygrpc.EOF:
            if self._cython_call.is_locally_cancelled():
                raise asyncio.CancelledError()
            else:
>               raise _create_rpc_error(self._cython_call._initial_metadata,
                                        self._cython_call._status)
E               grpc.aio._call.AioRpcError: <AioRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
E                       status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
E                       details = "Exception calling application: "
E                       debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {created_time:"2023-06-15T14:38:59.0601+02:00", grpc_status:2, grpc_message:"Exception calling application: "}"
E               >

../../../../Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/pytaf-6R8xcXyw-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/aio/_call.py:290: AioRpcError
```

I think it may have something to do with the server and client running both on the same asyncio runner but I'm not sure...
What is interesting is that https://pypi.org/project/pytest-grpc/ shows the same error but it is not clear for me what the fix would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours debugging, it seems like `server.stop()` was missing at the end of the call.

It is pretty miss-leading as an error information but calling `netstat -vanp tcp | grep 50051` enabled me to see that the port was kind of jammed and I had to `kill` one by one all the applications. By using `ps aux | grep <pid>` I could identify that previous running server where still there.

After killing all of them and running the test once more, it went through (besides the assert that is failing)

**Conclusion**

"StatusCode.UNKNOWN" may mean that the **port** is blocked!